# Ruling on haram money acquired out of ignorance as a salesperson

Tags: sharia

Peace be upon you.

My question is as follows: I work as a sales representative for a  marketing agency and my job is to bring in customers and then get a commission for each successful deal. About nine or ten months ago I brought a client and he has a project and I got a commission through cryptocurrency (ETH) because the deal was successful and I before I bring any client I try my best  to check the site of the project and social media accounts to make sure that the project doesn't have any haram thing and to guarantee halal money and I had checked the site of the project and I did not notice any haram thing and I told myself that the money I made is halal but today the same customer came and bought a package and I got  a commission and then I wanted to make sure again that the site doesn't have any haram thing, but when I checked, I found a 2D drawing from far and it has 2 naked girls and in one of the sections of the site, I see them talking about casino (where gambling is held), and then I kept looking for fatwas if the previous money I made 9 months ago was halal or haram, and I did not find a detailed fatwa because I was ignorant and did not know if the website had any of the haram things I mentioned above.

Sorry if my question was long, but I want a detailed fatwa in this matter, otherwise I will keep thinking about it, and may Allah reward you for what you are doing.

Comment: `I want a detailed fatwa` This site does not issue fatwaas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Allâh accepts only the repentance of those who do evil in **ignorance**
> and foolishness and repent soon afterwards; it is they whom Allâh will
> forgive and Allâh is Ever All-Knower, All-Wise. Quran 4:17

From the above verse it is clear that Allah accepts repentance if you commit evil out of ignorance.